# NumPy: How to avoid this loop?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Is there a way to avoid this loop so optimize the code?

```py
import numpy as np

cLoss = 0
dist_ = np.array([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]) # just an example, longer in reality
TLabels = np.array([-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1]) # just an example, longer in reality
t = float(dist_.size)
for i in range(len(dist_)):
    labels = TLabels[dist_ == dist_[i]]
    cLoss+= 1 - TLabels[i]*(1. * np.sum(labels)/t)
print cLoss
```

*Note:* `dist_` and `TLabels` are both numpy arrays with the same shape `(t,1)`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well I believe it's correct, `TLabels[dist_ == dist_[i]]` will return values from `TLabels` which have indices where `dist_ == dist_[i]`. For example let `dist_ = array([2,1,2])` and `TLabels=array([1,2,3])` so `dist_ == dist_[0]` will return `array([True,False,True])` than `TLabels[dist_ == dist_[0]] = array([1,3])`

Comment: Just to be clear, are the arrays `(t,1)` or `(t,)`?  Where is `cLoss` initialized?

Comment: You need to turn this into a full running (cut and paste) example, with output.  Otherwise we won't take it seriously.

Comment: Is `cLoss` initially `0` or `[]`.  And why the `return`?  You aren't defining a function.

Comment: Neither `t`, nor `dist_` (did you mean `dist`?), nor `cLoss` are defined.  This is still not a running example.  Until you can copy and paste the code into a fresh interpreter, it's not ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do, but are you aware of `scipy.ndimage.measurements` for computing on arrays with labels? It look like you want something like:

```
cLoss =  len(dist_) - sum(TLabels * scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum(TLabels,dist_,dist_) / len(dist_))
```

Answer (score 2):

I first wonder, what is `labels` at each step in the loop?

With `dist_ = array([2,1,2])` and `TLabels=array([1,2,3])`

I get

```
[-1  1]
[1]
[-1  1]
```

The different length immediately raise a warning flag - it may be difficult to vectorize this.

With the longer arrays in the edited example

```
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1]
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1]
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1]
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1]
[ 1  1  1  1 -1]
[-1  1 -1 -1 -1]
```

The `labels` vectors are all the same length.  Is that normal, or just a coincidence of values?

Drop a couple of elements off of `dist_`, and `labels` are:

```
In [375]: for i in range(len(dist_)):
        labels = TLabels[dist_ == dist_[i]]
        v = (1.*np.sum(labels)/t); v1 = 1-TLabels[i]*v
        print(labels, v, TLabels[i], v1)
        cLoss += v1
   .....:     
(array([-1,  1, -1, -1]), -0.25, -1, 0.75)
(array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 0.5, 1, 0.5)
(array([-1,  1, -1, -1]), -0.25, 1, 1.25)
(array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 0.5, 1, 0.5)
(array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 0.5, 1, 0.5)
(array([-1,  1, -1, -1]), -0.25, -1, 0.75)
(array([-1,  1, -1, -1]), -0.25, -1, 0.75)
(array([1, 1, 1, 1]), 0.5, 1, 0.5)
```

Again different lengths of labels, but really only a few calculations.  There is 1 `v` value for each different `dist_` value.

Without working out all the details, it looks like you are just calculating `labels*labels` for each distinct `dist_` value, and then summing those.

This looks like a `groupBy` problem.  You want to divide the `dist_` into groups with a common value, and sum some function of their corresponding `TLabels` values.  Python `itertools` has a `groupBy` function, so does `pandas`.  I think both require you to sort `dist_`.

Try sorting `dist_` and see if that adds any clarity to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is any better since I didn't exactly understand why you might want to do this. Many variables in your loop are bivalued hence can be computed in advance.

Also the entries of `dist_` can be used as a boolean switch but I used an explicit copy anyhow.

```
dist_        = np.array([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0])
TLabels      = np.array([-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1])
t            = len(dist) 
dist_zeros   = dist_== 0
one_zero_sum = [sum(TLabels[dist_zeros])/t , sum(TLabels[~dist_zeros])/t]

cLoss        = sum([1-x*one_zero_sum[dist_[y]] for y,x in enumerate(TLabels)])
```

which results in `cLoss = 8.2`. I am using Python3 so didn't check whether this is a true division or not in Python2.